# Temporarily change a value (text color) and restore it after some operation (printing text)

Tags: c#

I want to make "a variable" that changes text color to green for whatever you print in its curly braces however when curly braces are closed it changes console text color back to gray for the next things I print.

So for short what I wanted to do is this:

```
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
Console.WriteLine("test");
Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.gray;
```

but since I have this a lot in my code I want to short it like this:

```
mycmd(green, gray)
{
    Console.WriteLine("test");
}
```

Comment: Yes.  This is what [methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/methods) are for.

Comment: What you're looking for is called transclusion, and I'm not aware of C# having this capability.

Comment: @Scottie - transclusion is a new term for me so i looked it up.  i'm not seeing the link between this question and transclusion though.  open to persuasion...maybe Wikipedia has it wrong.

Comment: Don't know if this link will be of any value to you, but you might want to give it a look see. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/319883/how-to-change-foreground-colors-and-background-colors-of-text-in-a-con

Comment: @nocturns2 I don't think the question is about how to do that, but rather how to write code that restores colors back in somewhat automatic way (or maybe even broader - any value that changes and than need to be restored after some block of code is done)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could do something like this

```
public static void ColorAndWrite(ConsoleColor c1, ConsoleColor c2, string text)
{
   Console.ForegroundColor = c1;
   Console.WriteLine(text);
   Console.ForegroundColor = c2;
}
```

**usage**

```
ColorAndWrite(ConsoleColor.Black,ConsoleColor.Blue, "asdads");
```

or use an `Action`

```
public static void ColorFancy(ConsoleColor c1, ConsoleColor c2, Action action)
{
   Console.ForegroundColor = c1;
   action.Invoke();
   Console.ForegroundColor = c2;
}
```

**usage**

```
ColorFancy(ConsoleColor.Black, ConsoleColor.Blue, () =>  Console.WriteLine("dfgdfgdfgdfg"));

// or

ColorFancy(ConsoleColor.Black, ConsoleColor.Blue, () =>
      {
         // lots of things here
         Console.WriteLine("dfgdfgdfgdfg");
      });
```

Comment: @aGoodFellow all good, that was what the second example was about, personally i wouldn't abuse the dispose pattern like that, however its very common and legit. good luck

Comment: First of all thank you, because of the first one was predetermined code it can't be useful for every situation so i preferred second one however im having serious issues when it comes to using variables inside of it that connects to the program code.

Comment: @aGoodFellow might be better to ask another question, and show exactly what your problem is with the action approach. your question will be new again and drag in a lot more views and opinions,

Comment: got it, im sorry for the mess i made.

Answer (score 3):

You can create an `IDisposable` implementation and abuse `using`s for that

```
public class ConsoleColorBlock : IDisposable
{
    private readonly ConsoleColor _c2;

    public ConsoleColorBlock(ConsoleColor c1, ConsoleColor c2)
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = c1;
        _c2 = c2;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = _c2;
    }
}
```

And then in your code

```
using(new ConsoleColorBlock(ConsoleColor.Green, ConsoleColor.Gray))
{
    // Whatever code you want
}
```

Note that the code in the `Dispose` method will be executed even if the code inside the `using` throws an exception.

As suggested by @AlexeiLevenkov in the comments you can use this pattern to capture the current console color and restore it without explicitely passing it in the constructor.

```
public class ConsoleColorBlock : IDisposable
{
    private readonly ConsoleColor _originalColor;

    public ConsoleColorBlock(ConsoleColor color)
    {
        _originalColor = Console.ForegroundColor;
        Console.ForegroundColor = color;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Console.ForegroundColor = _originalColor;
    }
}
```

Comment: I like that pattern (even if half of the people consider it pure evil)... Note that normally you'd pass only one "new" value and code in constructor will capture "current" value to restore it later (possibly with static helpers for known values). like `using(ConsoleColorBlock.Red()) { Console.WriteLine("Alarm!!!"); }`

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Excellent point, I added an example for that.

Comment: Hmm im having a problem when i added `ConsoleKeyInfo remSelection = Console.ReadKey();` line because of the "remSelection" doesn't connect with the rest of the code. But thank you two for helping regardless.